# .htaccess file on prod and tracked in git, do not want to use prod's .htaccess on dev

Tags: git, .htaccess

If this is a duplicate, please mark it is as so. Also, I'm not exactly sure if this would be an opinion-based question. My googling has not returned anything relevant to my predicament, and I'm not sure what I should be googling either. ([1](https://www.google.com/search?q=different+htaccess+files+prod+dev), [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=two+repos+in+one+folder))

My question is about how to keep a production `.htaccess` file that is tracked in git from interfering with my development environment's web server.

A brief description of my git deployment setup:
Local machine (dev) -> Bitbucket -> Production

Production is on a shared host, so I can't directly push to production from dev, I have to use Bitbucket as an intermediary.

My development environment:
I use Vagrant locally as my development environment, which uses Apache as its web server. The vagrantbox setup script applies changes in the `httpd.conf` file to set up the `VirtualHost`, `DocumentRoot` and `DirectoryIndex`.

This has worked fine for me in the past.

On production, Apache is also used. I originally did not have `.htaccess` tracked in git, but there was a change recently (an HTTP to HTTPS redirect) that made me decide to start tracking it. The problem I have now is that the production `.htaccess` file is getting pulled to my dev directory and affecting my dev web server.

A few ideas I had were:

1. Creating a separate git repo to track the `.htaccess` file on production that will not be added to Bitbucket or dev, but this feels convoluted to me.
2. Creating a branch to track the `.htaccess` file but ... I foresee that getting messy for me because I'll be juggling branches on prod/dev and there's a strong chance I'd screw something up.
3. I forego tracking the `.htaccess` file altogether, but that seems like a recipe for disaster later on.

Is there another way to do this? Or should I use one of the ideas I thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branch aproach could be good idea, maybe a develop branch without the .htaccess files and a production branch like master with the tracking. So when you have something ready for production you do a merge to master.

Comment: I noticed the OP's question two minutes too late - you replied first :).  A "branch" (e.g. "dev") is probably *ideal* for cases like this.  To answer the OP's concern - there's no need for things to "get messy".  In a CI/CD environment, using branches would probably be *cleaner*.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. The project I'm using this for is pretty minor so I've been committing directly to `master` and only branching for features that I'm in the process of completing but are not ready for production. I suppose then I would create a `development` branch locally and remove the `master` branch. Bitbucket would have both `development` and `master`, and I could merge the `development` branch into `master` on Bitbucket, then pull `master` from production. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Exactly right.  You might not even need to merge.  Of course, another possibility is to have two files: one for prod, the other for dev.  You could save both, but put them in separate directories (/prod/.htaccess, /dev/.htaccess) or give them separate names (.htaccess.prod, .htaccess.dev).

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is probably the one you are looking for, however, there maybe a couple of alternatives without changing version control...

If your local dev environment does not use `.htaccess` at all, then you could disable this in your server config, then it wouldn't matter if the prod `.htaccess` file is present or not:

```
<Directory /path/to/public_html>
    # Disable .htaccess files...
    AllowOverride none
</Directory>
```

If you need `.htaccess` in both prod and dev but with (some) different directives then you can include conditionals in your `.htaccess` file. There are various ways you can do this, one way is to `Define` a variable in the server config of your dev server and check for this in `.htaccess`.

For example, in your server config:

```
Define DEV
```

In `.htaccess`:

```
<IfDefine DEV>
    # Development server directives...
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine !DEV>
    # Production server directives...
</IfDefine>
```

Note the `!` (not) prefix on the second rule block.

Comment: I like this approach better than keeping two branches, but having two branches in git is probably the correct way to solve the issue. I have trouble managing branches and remote hosts in git and I can see myself accidentally overwriting something in dev that would require a lot of work and file juggling for me to fix.

Comment: Yes, I agree, although "correct" maybe subjective - YMMV. I often use a single conditional in `.htaccess` to differentiate live/development servers as there may just be a small path difference between the two and it's often easier to maintain this together in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the exactly same problem ... what I'm currently doing is I keep my working dev directory under /var/www/site [dev]/ but I've gitignored the .htaccess files along with anything else that's only for development. Then I keep a second directory right next to it at /var/www/site [prod]/ with all the variations I want on the production server. So I commit and push from [dev], pull back down to [prod] and deploy from there. I mean, it works - but it feels like there should be an industry standard for stuff like this, which is why I'm here. But whatever, I guess if it works, it works. *shrugs*